# How can we calculate the probability?

Tags: probability

How can we calculate the probability of (x+y=z) where x on [0,n] and y on [0,m]

and z is constant value fro each BB (basic block)?

in more details

what I am going to calculate is I have a program and this program (its source code) is divided into basic blocks (say every basic block contain in average n instructions) ... now if an error happen in basic block and jump to another basic block in the same program ... now ... assume the processor executed x instructions in first basic block and after jump it executed y instructions in the jumped basic block or (new BB).. what is the probability of x+y=z

I am some confused about discrete and continuous but each basic block contain an integer number of instructions (for example BB1 has 12 instructions (BB1 i.e. basic block 1) and BB2 has 20 instructions ) etc. Assume the processor will start execution from BB1 then at the end of BB1 jump to beginning BB2 . for some unwanted error ... the control flow changed from the middle of BB1 to some where in BB2 ... now at the end of BB2 what is the probability of (x+y=z) ?

---

I would Thank you for your participation & for sweet comments for the valuable answers and comments.

The issue has become more exciting, and therefore I have to explain it in more detail and excuse me for not clarifying the question in detail since the beginning.

At first glance, some may think that the issue is outside the scope of the forum but it is quite the opposite.

At first I will define some terms then enter the heart of the matter.

Definition 1: A control flow errors (CFE) is an illegal branch which can be caused by transient faults in hardware such as the program counter, address circuit or memory system.

Definition 2: A Branch Free Block (BFB) is a sequence of non-branching instructions in the program. (Basic Block or BB)

Definition 3: A Partition Block (PB) is a set of instructions between two physically consequent BFBs. (these instruction to check the correctness of control flow of the program)

Definition 4: A program crash occurs when either the execution illegally continues inside/outside the program or the processor generates an exception as the result of a CFE (e.g., invalid opcode or page fault).

Definition 5: A CPU crash occurs when the CPU does not respond at all.

[fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1sRv.png)

Now, a CFG or Control flow graph 
(num 1 in fig 1)

example of CFG for an easy source code 
(num 2 in fig 1)

In order to detect control flow error (CFE) , there are a lot of software and hardware techniques. According to the following figure: 
(num 3 in fig 1)

There are seven types of CFEs, i.e., illegal branches
(BFB i.e. Basic Free Branch or Basic Block && PB the Partition Block)

CFE Type 1: From a BFB to another BFB

CFE Type 2: From a PB to itself or another PB

CFE Type 3: From a BFB to itself

CFE Type 4: From a PB to a BFB

CFE Type 5: From a BFB to a PB

CFE Type 6: From a BFB to outside the program area

CFE Type 7: From a PB to outside the program area

Let us look to this (num 4 in fig 1)

To calculate the probability of CFE type 1: (num 5 in fig 1)

---

NOW,

Let us look to this:
[false accumulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuXhC.jpg)

The processor executes 30 instructions (for example) and then for unwanted CFE control flow error, the processor jumps to incorrect BB (BB3) and in the worst cases, the processor jumps to place in the BB3 at the first of instruction which has the order number 31 and continued the executing until the last one. So it has execute 50 instruction in BB3 and 30 instruction in BB1 before the CFE has occurred. This is what I called false accumulation. In this case the additional instruction in PB (partition block) at the end of BB3 can't detect this error.

Therefore, the false accumulation occurs if and only if CFE-TYPE-1 has occurred + (x+y=z i.e. expected value for the incorrect BB). 
So , the formula should be like (num 6 in fig 1)

Where

X on [0-90], according to previous example, x=30

Y on [0-80], according to previous example, y=50

Z (expected value) = 80

So what is the probability of x + y = z ?

***Note:*** in a few article the Probability of jumping from BBi to BBj has introduced. But I don’t want explain them here because they assume x and y as a number of byte in each instruction (the length of instruction is 32 bit, so the y or x is a uniformly distributed variable)

***I do not want to complicate the problem***, just assume x and y is an integer number of instructions and as **@Mr. David K** said that uniform distributed is inappropriate in this case. Therefore x, y are discrete variables.

Anyway I'm sure that the probability of such an error is very small and may be closer to zero.

thanks

Comment: It will almost never happen

Comment: What do you  mean? Are you working with discrete spaces?

Comment: So you mean integers? I can answer this question _whether_ x and y are discrete or continuous.

Comment: x,y and z are uniformly distributed variables @ParclyTaxel

Comment: The questions about "discrete" or "continuous" are asking whether "$x$ in the range $0$ to $5$" means that $x$ is an _integer_ in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ or means that $x$ can be any real number such that $0\leq x \leq 5$ (for example, $1.234$ or $\sqrt2$). _Either one of these interpretations can describe a uniformly distributed variable,_ so simply saying it is "uniform" does not help much.

Comment: I would guess you mean for all the numbers to be integers, but if that is what you want, it is better to say it explicitly.

Comment: I am sorry , yes x is an integer number @DavidK

Comment: OK, from the comment on the answer (so far) it is clear that you must model $x$ and $y$ as integers, but I would not recommend a uniform distribution for the number of instructions executed within a block of code before an error occurs. You might get better answers if you copied that comment about number of instructions executed into the question itself.

Comment: The latest edit implies that the blocks of code involved are sequences of machine-code instructions rather than units of source code of a high-level programming language. Perhaps the question is best put, _given_ that a CFE (a hardware error that causes the sequence of execution to jump to an incorrect address) occurred, what is the probability that it jumps one block to instruction $n+1$ in another block, where $n$ is the number of instructions executed in the first block before the CFE?

Comment: Another way to look at a CFE is that it effectively adds some positive or negative number to the program counter (PC). It seems to me you will get a "false accumulation" when a CFE moves the PC from one block (say block $i$) to another (say block $j$) and the amount that the CFE added to the PC is precisely the difference of the starting address of block $j$ minus the starting address of block $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take $X$ to be the number of instructions successfully executed in block BB1, and $Y$ to be the number of instructions successfully executed in block BB2; so if the first instruction in BB1 has an error then $X=0$, but if BB1 has $10$ instructions and completes without error then $X=10$.

I think it's important that we're talking about instructions in a computer program here and not, for example, a game of Russian Roulette. Given a sequence of $10$ instructions in BB1, we do not load one bullet into a revolver with $10$ (or $11$) chambers and then pull the trigger repeatedly until the gun fires. Rather, either we have specific information about each instruction that gives the probability that it has an error (in which case we have a model with a lot more detailed information than the question has, and the probabilities may not be uniform), or we have only an idea that if we execute many instructions, some percentage of them will have errors, without knowing which instructions are more likely than others to fail.

Suppose we only know the expected percentage of instructions that will fail. We interpret this to mean that *if* a particular instruction is executed, it has some probability $p$ to fail.
The probability $p$ could be anywhere from $0$ to $1$, but once we find out what it is it is the same value for every instruction.
We also assume that whether a particular instruction has an error is independent of any errors that occur or do not occur in other instructions.

Although the probability $p$ is the same for every instruction, the number $X$ of instructions successfully executed *will not be uniformly distributed.*
The reason for this is that in order to get the result $X=n$, where $n$ is less than the length of BB1, not only must the $n+1$st instruction in BB1 have an error, but the first $n$ instructions in BB1 all must *not* have errors. If an earlier instruction had an error then the $n+1$st instruction would not be tried at all.

For example, suppose $p = 0.2$ ($20\%$ chance of an error). Then $X=0$ with probability $0.2$, because that is the probability that the very first instruction has an error. But $X=1$ with probability $0.16$, because this occurs only when the first instruction succeeds (probability $0.8$) *and* the second instruction has an error (probability $0.2$). The probability that *both* of these things happen is $0.8 \times 0.2 = 0.16$.
Altogether, the probability distribution of $X$ looks like this:
\begin{align}
P(X=0) &= 0.2 \\
P(X=1) &= 0.16\\
P(X=2) &= 0.128\\
P(X=3) &= 0.1024\\
P(X=4) &= 0.08192\\
P(X=5) &= 0.065536\\
P(X=6) &= 0.0524288\\
P(X=7) &= 0.04194304\\
P(X=8) &= 0.033554432\\
P(X=9) &= 0.0268435456\\
P(X=10) &= 0.1073741824
\end{align}
Notice how each probability (except for $P(X=10)$) is smaller than the one above it.
If $p=0.05$ ($5\%$ chance of an error) then the probabilities are
\begin{align}
P(X=0) &= 0.05\\
P(X=1) &= 0.0475\\
P(X=2) &= 0.045125\\
P(X=3) &= 0.04286875\\
P(X=4) &= 0.0407253125\\
P(X=5) &= 0.0386890469\\
P(X=6) &= 0.0367545945\\
P(X=7) &= 0.0349168648\\
P(X=8) &= 0.0331710216\\
P(X=9) &= 0.0315124705\\
P(X=10) &= 0.5987369392
\end{align}
That is, if the probability $p$ of error in a particular instruction is small, then BB1 will probably execute all $10$ of its instructions.

The general formula is
\begin{align}
P(X=k) &= (1-p)^k \times p & \text{if} \quad k < N,\\
P(X=N) &= (1-p)^N
\end{align}
where $N$ is the number of instructions in BB1.
If $p$ is *very* small then it is reasonable to say that $P(X=n) = p$ if $n<10$ and $P(X=10)= 1 - 10p$. This is still not a uniform distribution, however, because $p$ must be much smaller than $1/11$ for this to be even
a reasonable approximation.

If the program jumps to the first instruction of BB2 when it encounters
an error in BB1, then the probability distribution of $Y$ is
\begin{align}
P(X=k) &= (1-p)^k \times p & \text{if} \quad k < M,\\
P(X=N) &= (1-p)^M
\end{align}
where $M$ is the number of instructions in BB2.

Once you have found the probability distributions for $X$ and $Y$,
the probability distribution of $X+Y$ can be found by a summation:
$$
P(X+Y=z) = \begin{cases}
\sum_\limits{k=0}^{z} P(X=k)\times P(Y=z-k) & \text{if } z \leq M,\\
\sum_\limits{k=0}^{M} P(X=k)\times P(Y=z-k) & \text{if } M < z \leq N,\\
\sum_\limits{k=z-N}^{M} P(X=k)\times P(Y=z-k) & \text{if } z > N
\end{cases}
$$
where BB1 has $M$ instructions and BB2 has $N$ instructions.

These computations are tedious, so you would of course write a program
to do them. Each sum above can be computed as a single loop over the variable $k$, but rather than compute them that way, it is a little easier (and less error-prone) to write a program like the following pseudocode,
using an array of floating-point values $S$:
\begin{align}
&\text{for } z \text{ in } \{0, 1, \ldots, M + N\}\\
&\qquad S[z] = 0\\
&\text{for } j \text{ in } \{0, 1, \ldots, M\}\\
&\qquad \text{for } k \text{ in } \{0, 1, \ldots, N\}\\
&\qquad\qquad  z = j + k\\
&\qquad\qquad  S[z] := S[z] + P(X = j) \times P(Y = k)
\end{align}
When all these loops have completed then you can read the probability distribution from the array $S$ using the formula $P(X + Y = z) = S[z]$.

To find the probability that a total $z$ instructions will be executed in the first *three* blocks, let $X$ be the total number of instructions executed in BB1 and BB2 together (which is the probability distribution that we just computed, above) and let $Y$ be the total number of instructions
executed in BB3. Then call the pseudocode again, but this time use these new definitions for $P(X = j)$ and $P(Y = k)$.
You can continue redefining $X$ and $Y$ and recomputing the distribution
of their sum until you have the distribution of the sum of all ten
blocks of code, if you want.

If the program can jump to a point *after* the first instruction of BB2
when an error occurs in BB1, then things get more complicated,
because we cannot just use a probability distribution over $Y$
as if $P(Y=k)$ were independent of whatever happened before BB2
started executing.

Comment: Thank you very much @David K. Finding the probability distributions for X and Y is so difficult or it may be impossible because CFE result from transient faults is not deterministic. The transient fault like (SEU - Single Error Upset) strikes the Program counter register (PC) and led to change a single bit (bit-flip) for example 1000 >> 1100 .. 3th bit change from 0 to 1. and this is called CFE beause now the cpu will jump to that place where PC points to it.

Answer (score 3):

if $x,y$ are continuous random variables

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x=t)P(y=z-t) dt$

if $x$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,n]$ and $y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,m]$

$P(x=t) = \begin{cases} \frac 1n, &t \in [0,n]\\0,& t\notin [0,n]\end{cases}$

And lets suppose $m<n$

if $z<m$
$\int_{0}^{z} \frac 1{mn} dt = \frac z{mn}$

if $m<z<n$
$\int_{z-m}^{z} \frac 1{mn} dt = \frac {m}{mn}$

if $n<z$
$\int_{z-m}^{n} \frac 1{mn} dt = \frac {n+m-z}{mn}$

if $x,y$ are discretely distributed, then it is a similar idea, however we do it as a summation.

$P(x+y=z) = \begin{cases} \sum_\limits {i=0}^{z} \frac 1{(m+1)(n+1)} = \frac {(z+1)}{(m+1)(n+1)}, & z< m\\
\sum_\limits {i=z-m}^{z} \frac 1{(m+1)(n+1)} = \frac {m+1}{mn},& m\le z < n\\
\sum_\limits {i=z-m}^{n} \frac 1{(m+1)(n+1)} = \frac {n+m+1-z}{(m+1)(n+1)},& z\ge n\end{cases}$

The $+1$'s are there because there are $n+1$ integers in the interval $[0,n]$

Comment: thank you very much but really I can't understand you answer because I am a programmer and I must read more about probability. what I am going to calculate is I have a program and this program (its source code) is divided into basic blocks (say every basic block contain in average n instructions) ... now if an error happen in basic block and jump to another basic block in the same program ... now ... assume the processor executed x instructions in first basic block and after jump it executed y instructions in the jumped basic block or (new BB).. what is the probability of x+y=z

Comment: But you are posting on a math site :)  I put more detail in the discrete case which tends to be more typical of programming projects, and did the integration for you for the continuous case.

Comment: :) thank you very much... but you know it is indispensable for mathematics In the world of programming :) ... I am some confused about discrete and continuous but each basic block contain an integer number of instructions (for example BB1 has 12 instructions (BB1 i.e. basic block 1) and BB2 has 20 instructions ) etc. Assume the processor will start execution from BB1 then at the end of BB1 jump to beginning BB2 . for some unwanted error ... the control flow changed from the middle of BB1 to some where in BB2 ... now at the end of BB2  what is the probability of (x+y=z) :)  :)

Comment: which formula is more appropriate fro my question?

Comment: If you have discrete blocks distributed from [0,n] and [0,m] , then the one with $P(x+y=z)$ followed by the cases.  Do you know how to read the cases?  If z fits the critera of the first case (on the right hand side) then use $\frac {z+1}{(m+1)(n+1)}$ etc.

Comment: my workload (benchmark) is divided into 10 basic blocks that contain not the same number of instructions. BB1 has 10 ins, BB2 has 5 ins, BB3 has 23 ins and so on.